# Simple JSON object throws "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

I've written a small [framework for asynchronous resource loading (link)](http://github.com/IgelHaut/rscLoader). In most modern browsers like Opera, Chrome, Firefox it is working as expected.

I've also tried it in IE8, but the code doesn't execute. IE throws "Object doesn't support this property or method" on a simple well-formed [ checked via eval() ] JSON object.

How can I fix this or what causes this error?

Comment: can your post your json object or validate you json object here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: What is the line that throws the error?

Comment: Please update your question with the code of the line which throws the error. Also be aware that IE8 is missing some Javascript functions you'd like to think you can take for granted, like `string.trim()` and `Array.indexOf()`.

Comment: line 6 throws the error

Comment: @IgelHaut: looking at rscLoader.js in your GitHub repository (as of 2014/02/04), line 6 appears to be a comment.

Comment: It seems that the JSON object was malformed for IE... I had to replace single quotes ( ' ) with double quotes ( " ). Also I had to add the .indexOf() prototype for IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the error is raised because IE8 does not support [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Ref:

> indexOf was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such
>   it may not be present in all browsers. You can work around this by
>   utilizing the following code at the beginning of your scripts. This
>   will allow you to use indexOf when there is still no native support.
>   This algorithm matches the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition,
>   assuming TypeError and Math.abs have their original values.

Using the polyfill code:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
    "use strict";
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }
    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    var n = 0;
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      n = Number(arguments[1]);
      if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
        n = 0;
      } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
        n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
      }
    }
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }
    var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
    for (; k < len; k++) {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding indexOf to the Array prototype, you could use [underscorejs indexOf](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf). Because adding things to the Array prototype might lead to issues when using `for (x in array)` constructiuons and not using array.hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 1):

Array.indexOf isn't supported in IE8. You could either add it to the Array prototype as suggested by Irvin Dominin aka Edward. However this might cause problems iterating arrays using `for (x in array)` constructions when not using [array.hasOwnProperty(x)](http://brianflove.com/2013/09/05/javascripts-hasownproperty-method/).

Maybe you could use [underscorejs contains function](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) like this:

```
_.contains(resourceType[t].type, src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('.')+1))
```

Since you are writing a framework for loading files, you might not want to depend on any other thirdparty frameworks. In your case I would neither go for polyfilling Array with indexOf nor using a thirdparty solution such as underscore's `_.contains` function.
I would just write a simple functions which searches for a value in a index like:

```
function arrayContains(array, element) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The array prototype is my preferred choice, because an other library is just more weight... As you can see my little framework can be used as a preloader, it would just be very ugly to wait until the preloader  is ready and then load the other contents.

Comment: I see; good point. But you as a 'thirdparty' framework should not add anything to build-in js objects such as Array. Users of your framework might use the `for (x in array)` construction without checking for array.hasOwnProperty.